# Internet Explorer Touch Delay

Tags: internet-explorer, touch

I just noticed this today, and now it's really bugging me. Internet Explorer (11 in my case, may not matter), has a delay when you touch buttons or links. Using a mouse is instantaneous, but using a touchscreen adds around a ~500ms delay. Chrome does not have this same delay.

You can try it out yourself by visiting a sight like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) which uses anchor links on the side menus. Using a mouse, you can navigate instantly in any browser. Using IE specifically with touch creates a delay on every tap.

Most people probably don't notice it since we spend much of our time waiting for pages to load.

How do I turn off this delay?

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the latencies here:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TouchPredict`

This made a massive difference on the Surface RT for me.

Comment: It's not a screen issue. In fact, when you tap, it instantly highlights what you clicked on, but waits to actually fire the event. In any event, I actually answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer on the [Telerik Blog](http://blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-11-21/what-exactly-is.....-the-300ms-click-delay)

Summary: This is common, and can be turned off through a number of HTML/JavaScript/CSS solutions.

For me, I just added this CSS to my code:

```
a[href], button {
    -ms-touch-action: none; /* IE10 */
    touch-action: none;     /* IE11 */
}
```

It's now instant on my Lenovo, and my Surface 2.